# apache url rewrite with multiple parameters keep parameter=value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this

```
fullarticle.php?sID=3&ssID=21&id=1496
sID = category (Forums, entertaiment, news, sports etc)
ssID = sub category (businnes, health, crime, etc)
id = article id
```

My goal is to make that url look like this

```
fullarticle/News/Crimes/title
```

I've tried this at `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ fullarticle.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L,NC,QSA]
```

another one

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z\+]+)/([a-zA-Z\+\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ fullarticle.php?sID=3&ssID=21&id=1496
```

And some other with no luck.

How can I write a rule/condition to accomplish that? If there is an easier way to do this I am open to suggestions.

Thanks for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: "I have a url like this" ... "to make that url look like this" - to make it look like that you first need to change the URL in your application to make it _look like that_. Have you already done that? (Apologies, but I have to ask, since so many ask the same question, without doing this first step, expecting to do the whole thing in .htaccess.)

Comment: no worries. in my php i generate urls like  fullarticle.php?sID=3&ssID=21&id=1496. I have tried many RewriteRules trying to make it look like  fullarticle/news/crime with no luck.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816342/creating-static-seo-friendly-urls-with-mod-rewrite
http://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/
http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html

Comment: (Your PHP should be generating the URLs in the format you want them to look to your users.) How would you intend to convert `/news/crime` to `sID=3&ssID=21` etc.? Where do you get the numeric ID's from?

Comment: I don't want confrontation but I believe that is what RewriteRule is for. The problem is that all the rules/condition I tried still don't work. Any constructive reply would be appreciated.

Comment: It was just an honest question... mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) is just a URL rewriting engine, it's not capable of DB lookups (unless statically written in a server-side _map_). So, for example, where do you get `3` when `news` is given and `21` for `crime` when it's not actually present in the original URL? You would need to include this information somehow eg. `fullarticle/News-3/Crimes-21/title-1496`

Comment: that gives me a clue. Probably I will able to answer my own question soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to map from names to numeric ids. But this requires to set up such a map before, e.g.

categories.txt:

```
news 1
sports 2
entertainement 3
```

subcategories.txt:

```
crime 11
baseball 21
football 22
movie 31
```

titles.txt:

```
rewrite-rules-solved 83
stackoverflow-rocks 77
you-are-the-greatest 27
```

and then use that in a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteMap cat "txt:/path/to/categories.txt"
RewriteMap sub "txt:/path/to/subcategories.txt"
RewriteMap title "txt:/path/to/titles.txt"

RewriteRule ^/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$ fullarticle.php?sID=${cat:$1}&ssID=${sub:$2}&id=${title:$3} [L]
```

---

Instead of `txt` files, you can also use [`prg`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) or [`dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd) mappings. This would allow to retrieve the name to id mapping from a program or an SQL select statement. See the `RewriteMap` manual for more details.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. That actually works. However; it is going to be lot of work for maintenance. Our Categories, sub Categories, and title come from the database and keeps on adding/changing. 

I was thinking into converting the urls to fullarticle/News-3/Crimes-21/title-1496 and get the values from it. I am the process of separating News and 3, Crimes and 21, etc. Thanks again

Comment: If you have these already in a database, you could try a `prg` or `dbd` mapping instead of a `txt` file. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions Olaf. I appreciate that. However; I needed this working right away. I promise thought that I will look into prg or dbd which are topics out of my league at this point but looks promising for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was build my dynamic URLs like this:

`fullarticle/3/21/1496/title.html`

where 3 = category, 21 = sub category and 1496 = title id

My rewrite looks like this:

`RewriteRule ^fullarticle/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ fullarticle.php?sID=$1&ssID=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]`

I am a novice and it only took me 6 hours to figure it out. I am proud of my self!

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so everybody can see the question is resolved.